# int_log2(X,Y) which sets Y to the integer log2 of X, where X is assumed to be a nonnegative integer

Tags: prolog

I got the following task:

`int_log2(X,Y)` which sets `Y` to the integer `log2 of X`, where `X` is assumed to be a non-negative integer. For example `int_log(133,X)` will set `X to 7`. The integer `log base 2 of X` means the number of times you divide `X`by `2` to get down to one.  Where *divide* means integer division. Use nothing more than `+` and `div` to code it.

This is what I got so far. I am not 100% sure if I should do it like this. When I run query `int_log(133,Z)`, it only shows answer in true or false.

```
div(0,X).
div(X,Z) :- X \=0,  X1 is X-1, div(X1,W), Z is floor(X/2).

int_log(0,X).
int_log(X,Z) :- X \= 0,  X1 is X-1, int_log(X1,W), div(W,Z).
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is with such exercises, the problem statement already contains the answer.

> `X` is assumed to be a **non-negative integer**

```
% precondition( integer(X) ).
% precondition( X > 0 ).
```

> ... the number of times you divide `X` by 2 to get down to **one**

```
int_log2(1, 0).
int_log2(X, Y) :-
```

> ... the **number of times** you divide `X` by 2...
>
> ... Use **nothing more** than `+` and `div` to code it.

```
    X0 is X div 2, % used `div`
    int_log2(X0, Y0),
    Y is Y0 + 1. % used `+`
```

So this works like this:

```
?- int_log2(133, X).
X = 7 .

?- int_log2(256, X).
X = 8 .

?- int_log2(255, X).
X = 7 .
```

What will happen if you try to look for more solutions? Where does the choice point come from? How can you get rid of it? How can you get rid of it without using a cut?

Is this for a math course or a "Prolog" course? If it is meant to teach you Prolog, you will have a bad time.

As for how one would solve it: if you are using an implementation that has the arithmetic function [`msb()`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=f%28msb/1%29), you just say:

```
Y is msb(X).
```

for example:

```
?- X is msb(133).
X = 7.

?- X is msb(256).
X = 8.
```